# Option buttons unnecessarily linked Excel

Tags: vba, excel, radio-button

I am trying to make a 'simple' tool to calculate monthly subscription costs when different packages are selected. Of my available option buttons only one can be selected, but also none can be selected.

To accomplish this I added an extra option button that sets the price back to 0,00.

It looks like this:

[image]

[option list working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upuOU.jpg)
But, for some reason the button "n.v.t" (which is supposed to set the price to 0,00) is linked to the first button called "basis". I cannot select these separately which really takes away the point of using option buttons instead of check boxes.

[buttons being linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj9Po.jpg)

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and how I fix this? Maybe an alternative way of reaching my goal?

This is my first post so forgive me if this is not according what you are all used to. Also the reason why there are links instead of images (which you can find by clicking the link)

Answer (score 0):

You could name the options buttons using the box just left of the formula field.  If you select the radio button it should say something like: `OptionButton1` by default Then you could use some simple code in VBA to unCheck the other options when nvt is selected. Then use code like this in a module:

```
Public Sub nvt_click()
    If Sheets("SheetName").OptionButtons("rbNVT") = 1 Then
        Sheets("SheetName").OptionButtons("OptionButton1") = 0
        Sheets("SheetName").OptionButtons("OptionButton2") = 0
        '....
    End If
End Sub
```

Then right click the nvt option button and `assign macro` to `nvt_click()`.

Hope this gets you in the right direction.